# Would it make sense to use the feminine version of an adjective when describing a pronoun for a feminine noun?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord

I was recently asked to translate the following sentence:

> Gabrielle has biology. It is boring.

I was taught the word "ennuyeux" for the masculine form of boring and the feminine version "ennuyeuse". I thought that it would be appropriate to use the feminine version because it is describing the class *biologie* which is feminine. Would it be correct to do so or should I just use the masculine version?

Comment: When you say: She has biology, does that mean: She's looking at all the courses, and she has biology [has to take it, it's on the list]. Or does it mean: She has biology [now], as in a biology class? ***That can make a difference to the translation***.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on how you build your French sentence but the most straightforward translation would be:

> *C'est ennuyeux*

The adjective needs to agree with the neutral pronoun *ce* (*c'*) which is technically always masculine and singular, regardless of what it refers to.

Not sure about the English sentence, but the French one would be ambiguous. What is *ennuyeux* might be the biology class but also the fact Gabrielle is attending that class.

To sort it out, you might write:

> *Gabrielle a biologie, c'est une matière ennuyeuse.* (boring)

and for the alternate meaning:

> *C'est ennuyeux, Gabrielle a biologie.* (*ennuyeux* = troublesome/annoying here)

Answer (score 3):

"ennuyeux" here doesn't refer to "biology" but to the fact that Gabrielle has a biology lesson. This notion is not feminine, thus you can't use the feminine for "ennuyeux".

"It is" will be translated by "C'est", "c'" being the shortened form of "ça" which refers to the whole previous sentence (and is masculine).

Comment: ***C'est*** is the shortened and mandatory form of ***ce** est*. It doesn't come from ***ça** est* which is a very relaxed or regional French expression, the common one being ***cela** est*.

Comment: @jlliagre I am not sure to understand what you want to say. *c'est* is shortened from *cela est*, and *cela* is itself often shortened to *ça* (I wouldn't call it "very relaxed", *cela* is the correct formal form but in spoken language *ça* is way more common). *ce est* on the other hand simply doesn't mean anything.
You could technically find *cela est* without the shortening in especially formal situations, but *ça est* would be both too and not enough formal, so indeed you wouldn't hear that (except, you are right, as a regional expression)

Comment: You misunderstood indeed. *Ce est* **does** mean something but is never written that way, that must be **c'est**. No need to introduce *ça* / *cela*, even while they are close. Changing the verb tense makes: **ce sera ennuyeux**, **ce serait ennuyeux** or **ce fut ennuyeux** which confirm the pronoun can be and is **ce** at the present too. On the other hand, *ça sera ennuyeux* is possible but *ça fut ennuyeux* is unused, because of a register mismatch. We write *cela fut ennuyeux*. I'm not ruling out the possibility for someone to use *c'est* for *ça est* but that would be an exception.